# Throttling respawn - Error message in Console.app

Tags: macos, logging, console-application

I'm getting this error message every 10 seconds.

```
2011-02-09 05.54.37 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[153]  (com.mysql.mysqld) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

I'm running OS X 10.6.6.

Anyone knows what the problem may be and how do solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a situation that's been around in Unices for donkey's years.  Your program is exiting immediately as soon as it is invoked, leading to it be restarted over and over by `launchd`.  `launchd` has noticed this and stopped respawning the program.  The standard advice on this goes back many years, too:  Find out why the daemon process is immediately exiting rather than running, and fix the cause of that.  (It's usually a daemon misconfiguration of some kind.)

Yes, technically, in Mac OS 10 speak this is an "agent" rather than a "daemon", but that doesn't change either the nature of the problem or what you have to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

http://web.archive.org/web/20101024201347/http://blog.sirkevi.com/files/Removing_MacOSX_software_that_are_constantly_relaunched.php

Quoting:

> These following commands helped a lot
>
> ```
> launchctl list -> shows a list of autostart services
> launchctl remove com.webex.asassist
> launchctl remove com.webex.taskwatcher
> ```